# Best way to validate a name in Python

Tags: python, validation

I need to validate a name without regular expressions and keep it simple, i have this:

```
def validation(name):
    for char in name:
        if  not (("A" <= char and char <= "Z") or ("a" <= char and char <= "z") or (char == " ")):
            return False
    return True
```

is there a way to  make it better?

Comment: Why not regex?.......`^[a-zA-Z]$` done

Comment: Obligatory: [Falsehoods programmers believe about names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: In case you are interested, your logic could be further simplified as `if char == ' ' or ("A" <= char <= "Z") or ("a" <= char <= "z") continue; else: return False`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need the [isalpha()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha) method

```
name = "oridm"
if name.replace(" ", "").isalpha():
    print "Name is valid"
else:
    print "Name is invalid"
```

Answer (score 4):

There is useful list `string.letters` that contains all english letters, so you code may be written as one-liner:

```
import string

all(c in string.letters + ' ' for c in name)
```

Comment: This doesn't check for spaces though.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe, it does - note `+ ' '`

Comment: @FrerichRaabe the spaces can be anywhere in the string, and of any number. E.g. "John Doe" = True, as does "John D o e" and "JohnDoe"

Answer (score 2):

```
import re 
pattern = re.compile(r'([a-zA-Z])\D*([a-zA-Z])$')
pattern.search('string you're searching')
```

This - or something close to it - will allow you to parse the string. It looks for the first string, then ignores optional separators ( \D* ) of non-digits, then the final string.

Comment: @myaut is the better answer.

Comment: You missed the quotes within the compile method; also remove the `=` in the pattern.search :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

def validate_user(username, minlen):
"""Checks if the received username matches the required conditions."""
if type(username) != str:
    raise TypeError("username must be a string")
if minlen < 1:
    raise ValueError("minlen must be at least 1")

# Usernames can't be shorter than minlen
if len(username) < minlen:
    return False
# Usernames can only use letters, numbers, dots and underscores
if not re.match('^[a-z0-9._]*$', username):
    return False
# Usernames can't begin with a number
if username[0].isnumeric():
    return False
return True
```

Comment: The OP **explicitly** said **without regular expression**, which means this is not a valid answer. And could you please fix the indentation.